# In R sum(1:10) ,Error in sum(1:10) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

Tags: r

My computer R using RStudio

```
sum(1:10)
```

> Error in sum(1:10) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

Why?

Another internet, that `sum(1:5)` ok.
But in my computer's R `sum(1,2,3,4,5)` this is ok.
But `sum(1:5)` is not ok:

> Error in sum(1:5) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

Why?

Comment: Use c(1:10)....

Comment: @Christoph `c(1:10)` and `1:10` are `identical()`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a `sum` function that is masking the system `sum` function.

`sum` works properly for me:

```
> sum(1:10)
[1] 55
> sum(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
[1] 55
```

But if I create a function called `sum` with two arguments then I can break it in the same way you describe:

```
> sum = function(x,y){x+y}
```

Then this works because it expects exactly two arguments:

```
> sum(23,42)
[1] 65
```

but `1:10` is only one argument, so `y` is missing:

```
> sum(1:10)
Error in sum(1:10) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

Solution: remove the `sum` function and it all works again:

```
> rm(sum)
> sum(1:10)
[1] 55
>
```

Comment: oh, you are my r-god. it works. Thank you.  Thank you. Thank you.